# Поиск элемента строки в ключах массива

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строки такого вида

```
H 40%
K 45%, S 15%
K 15%, RUB 23%, SH 20%
```

И массив

```
var array = {'H': 'Hlopok','K': 'Karton','RUB': 'Rubin','SH': 'Shelk'};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы получился такой результат

```
Hlopok 40%
Karton 45%, S 15%
Karton 15%, Rubin 23%, Shelk 20%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var str = 'H 40% K 45%, S 15% K 15%, RUB 23%, SH 20%';
var array = {'H': 'Hlopok','K': 'Karton','RUB': 'Rubin','SH': 'Shelk'};

result = str.replace(/\w+(?=\s\d+%)/g, m => array[m] ? array[m] : m);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо, как раз то что нужно

Comment: @GooxFoxy, не за что :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```js
const stringList = [
    'H 40%',
    'K 45%, S 15%',
    'K 15%, RUB 23%, SH 20%',
];

const match = {'H': 'Hlopok','K': 'Karton','RUB': 'Rubin','SH': 'Shelk'};

const regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(match).join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');

console.log(stringList.map((str) => str.replace(regex, (matched) => match[matched])));
```

Comment: Извините, но строки находятся не в массиве

Comment: спасибо за ваш вариант, он тоже неплох

Comment: @GooxFoxy, в моем решении не имеет значения, одна строка или несколько в массиве